# Adding links to jekyll csv tabulation

Tags: jekyll

I am using the jekyll csv tutorial [here](https://jekyllrb.com/tutorials/csv-to-table/). I am not a ruby or jekyll expert and am using it to build out a github pages site.

Is there a way I can add a 4th column with links so that it is parsed correctly. Simply adding something like the below does not work. And yes, I want to link two files there.

`1. [Link Title 1](/mydatafolder/file1.html)  <br> 2. [Link Title 2](/mydatafolder/file2.html)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `{% capture %}` the input and `markdownify` it:

```
{% capture input %}
1. [Link Title 1](/mydatafolder/file1.html)  
2. [Link Title 2](/mydatafolder/file2.html)
{% endcapture %}
{{ input | markdownify }}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the same solution but it's not working.  The only difference is that I'm trying to use an external link instead.  

To confirm, this should be placed in the .csv file column, correct?

Answer (score 0):

One fairly verbose solution: rather than using markdown put in the full html href tag into the csv.

`<a href = "/mydatafolder/file1.html)">Link Title</a>`

There might be a more preferred jekyll/ruby way -- but as a beginner the above worked.

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of @[iBug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5958455/ibug) answer.  I found an even easier way to accomplish this.  Adding the `markdownify` filter does the job.

In the page file that reads the CSV file simply change:

```
    {% tablerow pair in row %}
      {{ pair[1] }}
    {% endtablerow %}
```

to

```
    {% tablerow pair in row %}
      {{ pair[1] | markdownify }}
    {% endtablerow %}
```

After this, your CSV file should accept markdown formatting as

```
 1. [Link Title 1](/mydatafolder/file1.html)  <br> 2. [Link Title 2](/mydatafolder/file2.html)
```